# are female bonobos "always" pregnant?

Tags: ethology, sex

Given that bonobo chimps are more sexually active then humans, are the females almost always pregnant? if not how not?

also are they so sexually active in the wild as well or is it just in captivity?

Answer (score 3):

In most species, females are pregnant as often as they can be. Since the availability of sex is rarely a limiting factor, it seems likely that female bonobos are as "always" pregnant as other chimps and socially living primates. The actual rate of pregnancy will be hormonally limited by things such as reduced fertility during lactation and so on.

Comment: I think this is normally true for humans - we only need to have sex once a month to make this true - not nearly as often as bonobos.